# Temporarily stop all systemd timer units

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I am writing a script that prepares my Linux system for benchmarking. Among other things I want to stop all systemd timer units, and revert this action afterwards.

**In short, I need the equivalent of** `service crond stop/start`.

All I have found so far is `systemctl list-timers` and then manually stop each one, and afterwards manually start each. Do you know of any better, more generic solutions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To stop all currently running timers, you can simply use:

```
systemctl stop '*.timer'
```

To restart the timers later, you’ll have to remember which ones were running at the time.

```
timers=$(systemctl list-units --type=timer --state=active --no-legend | awk '{print $1}')
systemctl stop $timers
# ...
systemctl start $timers
```

(Apparently patterns for units don’t match inactive units, so `systemctl start '*.timer'` doesn’t work.)

Comment: Thanks! For me the wildcard works for stopping all timers, but not for starting them.

Comment: Huh, indeed, I hadn’t tried that out. I’ve updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: This seems to be the best way currently available, so I'm accepting your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I don't see an option for this in `man systemctl` or `man systemd.timer`

On a relatively clean system, there are likely only a small number that might run during your benchmark. So after you run the `systemctl stop` commands the first the time, the next time save your stop/start commands in bash scripts, and just automate the stop/start commands that way.